# Why am I getting command not found error on numeric comparison?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, comparison

I am trying to parse each line of a file and look for a particular string. The script seems to be doing its intended job, however, in parallel it tries to execute the if command on line 6:

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in $(cat $1)
do
echo $line | grep -e "Oct/2015"
  if($?==0); then
  echo "current line is: $line"
  fi
done
```

and I get the following (my script is readlines.sh)

```
./readlines.sh: line 6: 0==0: command not found
```

Comment: BTW, this is #10 in the BashPitfalls page at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Just a suggestion, its not recommended to user for loop (instead use while) for reading file line by line, see link http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for more info.

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: also, `echo $line` is buggy -- if your line contains `*`, for instance, it will be replaced with a list of files in your current directory. Use `echo "$line"` instead, or (even better) `printf '%s\n' "$line"`. Though none of those should be needed in this particular use case. [This also is given in the BashPitfalls page]

Comment: ...I'd actually suggest running `grep` only once, on the *whole file*, not on individual lines, and then reading its output (containing only the lines you want) into your script; much, much faster than reading the full file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: As Mr. Llama says, you need more spaces. Right now your script tries to look for a file named something like `/usr/bin/0==0` to run. Instead:

```
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] # POSIX-compliant numeric comparison
[ "$?" = 0 ]   # POSIX-compliant string comparison
(( $? == 0 ))  # bash-extended numeric comparison
```

---

Second: Don't test `$?` at all in this case. In fact, you don't even have good cause to use `grep`; the following is both more efficient (because it uses only functionality built into bash and requires no invocation of external commands) and more readable:

```
if [[ $line = *"Oct/2015"* ]]; then
  echo "Current line is: $line"
fi
```

---

If you really *do* need to use `grep`, write it like so:

```
if echo "$line" | grep -q "Oct/2015"; then
  echo "Current line is: $line"
fi
```

That way `if` operates directly on the pipeline's exit status, rather than running a second command testing `$?` and operating on *that* command's exit status.

Comment: Thank you Charles. I am new to bash scripting so I tried what I found first.

Comment: Might want to put a `>/dev/null` after the grep unless you want it showing up on-screen.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, Good catch, but the better remediation to use `grep -q` in that case.

Comment: And last but not least, don't use `for line in $(cat "$1") ; ... done`, use `IFS= read -r line ; do ; ... done < "$1"` - see [this testcase](http://www.fraglimit.net/~collin/stuff/for-subshell-cat) for the difference.

Comment: @Sorpigal, indeed -- I don't cover any of that code here, but think it was adequately addressed in the comments on the question.

Answer (score 2):

@Charles Duffy has a good answer which I have up-voted as correct (and it is), but here's a detailed, line by line breakdown of your script and the correct thing to do for each part of it.

```
for line in $(cat $1)
```

As I noted in my comment elsewhere this should be done as a `while read` construct instead of a `for cat` construct.

- This construct will wordsplit each line making spaces in the file separate "lines" in the output.
- All empty lines will be skipped.

In addition when you cat `$1` the variable should be quoted. If it is not quoted spaces and other less-usual characters appearing in the file name will cause the cat to fail and the loop will not process the file.

The complete line would read:

```
while IFS= read -r line
```

An illustrative example of the tradeoffs [can be found here](http://www.fraglimit.net/~collin/stuff/for-subshell-cat). The linked test script follows. I tried to include an indication of why `IFS=` and `-r` are important.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /tmp/testcase
pushd /tmp/testcase >/dev/null

printf '%s\n' '' two 'three three' '' '    five with leading spaces' 'c:\some\dos\path' '' > testfile

printf '\nwc -l testfile:\n'

wc -l testfile

printf '\n\nfor line in $(cat) ... \n\n'

let n=1
for line in $(cat testfile) ; do
    echo line $n: "$line"
    let n++
done

printf '\n\nfor line in "$(cat)" ... \n\n'

let n=1
for line in "$(cat testfile)" ; do
    echo line $n: "$line"
    let n++
done

let n=1
printf '\n\nwhile read ... \n\n'

while read line ; do
    echo line $n: "$line"
    let n++
done < testfile

printf '\n\nwhile IFS= read ... \n\n'

let n=1
while IFS= read line ; do
    echo line $n: "$line"
    let n++
done < testfile

printf '\n\nwhile IFS= read -r ... \n\n'

let n=1
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    echo line $n: "$line"
    let n++
done < testfile

rm -- testfile

popd >/dev/null

rmdir /tmp/testcase
```

Note that this is a bash-heavy example. Other shells do not tend to support `-r` for read, for example, nor is `let` portable. On to the next line of your script.

```
do
```

As a matter of style I prefer do on the same line as the `for` or `while` declaration, but there's no convention on this.

```
echo $line | grep -e "Oct/2015"
```

The variable `$line` should be quoted here. In general, meaning *always unless you specifically know better*, you should double-quote all expansion--and that means subshells as well as variables. This insulates you from most unexpected shell weirdness.

You decclared your shell as `bash` which means you will have there "Here string" operator `<<<` available to you. When available it can be used to avoid the pipe; each element of a pipeline executes in a subshell, which incurs extra overhead and can lead to unexpected behavior if you try to modify variables. This would be written as

```
grep -e "Oct/2015" <<<"$line"
```

Note that I have quoted the `line` expansion.

You have called `grep` with `-e`, which is not incorrect but is needless since your pattern does not begin with `-`. In addition you have full-quoted a string in shell but you don't attempt to expand a variable or use other shell interpolation inside of it. When you don't expect and don't want the contents of a quoted string to be treated as special by the shell you should single quote them. Furthermore, your use of `grep` is inefficient: because your pattern is a fixed string and not a regular expression you could have used `fgrep` or `grep -F`, which does string contains rather than regular expression matching (and is far faster because of this). So this could be

```
grep -F 'Oct/2015' <<<"$line"
```

Without altering the behavior.

```
if($?==0); then
```

This is the source of your original problem. In shell scripts commands are separated by whitespace; when you say `if($?==0)` the `$?` expands, probably to 0, and `bash` will try to execute a command called `if(0==0)` which is a legal command name. What you wanted to do was invoke the `if` command and give it some parameters, which requires more whitespace. I believe others have covered this sufficiently.

You should never need to test the value of `$?` in a shell script. The `if` command exists for branching behavior based on the return code of whatever command you pass to it, so you can inline your `grep` call and have `if` check its return code directly, thus:

```
if grep -F 'Oct/2015` <<<"$line" ; then
```

Note the generous whitespace around the `;` delimiter. I do this because in shell whitespace is usually required and can only sometiems be omitted. Rather than try to remember when you can do which I recommend an extra one space padding around everything. It's never wrong and can make other mistakes easier to notice.

As others have noted this `grep` will print matched lines to stdout, which is probably not something you want. If you are using GNU `grep`, which is standard on Linux, you will have the `-q` switch available to you. This will suppress the output from `grep`

```
if grep -q -F 'Oct/2015' <<<"$line" ; then
```

If you are trying to be strictly standards compliant or are in any environment with a `grep` that doesn't know `-q` the standard way to achieve this effect is to redirect stdout to `/dev/null/`

```
if printf "$line" | grep -F 'Oct/2015' >/dev/null ; then
```

In this example I also removed the here string bashism just to show a portable version of this line.

```
echo "current line is: $line"
```

There is nothing wrong with this line of your script, except that although `echo` is standard implementations vary to such an extent that it's not possible to absolutely rely on its behavior. You can use `printf` anywhere you would use `echo` and you can be fairly confident of what it will print. Even `printf` has some caveats: Some uncommon escape sequences are not evenly supported. See [mascheck](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) for details.

```
printf 'current line is: %s\n' "$line"
```

Note the explicit newline at the end; printf doesn't add one automatically.

```
    fi
```

No comment on this line.

```
done
```

In the case where you did as I recommended and replaced the `for` line with a `while read` construct this line would change to:

```
done < "$1"
```

This directs the contents of the file in the `$1` variable to the stdin of the `while` loop, which in turn passes the data to `read`.

In the interests of clarity I recommend copying the value from `$1` into another variable first. That way when you read this line the purpose is more clear.

I hope no one takes great offense at the stylistic choices made above, which I have attempted to note; there are many ways to do this (but not a great many *correct*) ways.

Be sure to always run interesting snippets through the excellent [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and [explain shell](http://explainshell.com/) when you run into difficulties like this in the future.

And finally, here's everything put together:

```
#!/bin/bash
input_file="$1"
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    if grep -q -F 'Oct/2015' <<<"$line" ; then
        printf 'current line is %s\n' "$line"
    fi
done < "$input_file"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response

Answer (score 1):

If you like one-liners, you may use AND operator (`&&`), for example:

```
echo "$line" | grep -e "Oct/2015" && echo "current line is: $line"
```

or:

```
grep -qe "Oct/2015" <<<"$line" && echo "current line is: $line"
```

Comment: You're not actually using `||` here at all (which is good -- the "ternary" idiom often done with both `&&` and `||` in a single command is broken -- but it might be worth cleaning up the text a little to remove the reference).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Spacing is important in shell scripting.
Also, double-parens is for numerical comparison, not single-parens.

```
if (( $? == 0 )); then
```

Comment: One caveat: The double-paren syntax given here is a bash extension. Your question is tagged bash, so that's fine, but be aware that you can't safely use it in a script starting with `#!/bin/sh`. (`$(( ))`, by contrast, is POSIX-specified and safe in `/bin/sh` scripts).